# Importing variables from other files

Tags: javascript, import, discord.js

I am trying to import a variable from one of my files (File 1) and use it in File 2. I have imported File 2 into File 1 but I am receiving error. My channel ID is correct, in this case you would have to choose the channel so the channel ID is not the issue here.
`TypeError: setr.send is not a function`

**File 1**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios");
let config = require("../config.json");


module.exports = {
  name: "setrestart",
  description: "sets the restart channel",
  async execute(message, args) {


    const perm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(":x: You do not have permission to use this command.")
      .setColor("#E74C3C");

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send(perm);
    if (message.author.id !== "ID")
      return message.channel.send(perm);

    const channelx =
      message.mentions.channels.first() ||
      message.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === args[0]);
    if (!channelx)
      return message.channel.send(
        `:x: Please specify the channel where server restarts will go!`
      );

    message.reply(`All server restart logs will now go to ${channelx}.`)
  },    
};
```

**File 2**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios");
let config = require("../config.json");
let setr = require("./setrestart"); // This is importing file 1

module.exports = {
  name: "restart",
  description: "send a restart message in status channel",
  async execute(message, args) {
    const perm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(":x: You do not have permission to use this command.")
      .setColor("#E74C3C");

    if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"))
      return message.channel.send(perm);
    if (message.author.id !== "ID")
      return message.channel.send(perm);

    

    const restart = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(" Server Restarted! ")
      .setDescription(`F8 connect to ${config.SERVER_URL} `)
      .setColor("RANDOM")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter(`${config.SERVER_LOGO}`);

      setr.channelx.send(restart) // This does not work.
  },    
};
```

Help is much appreciated.

**Edit**: I left out the most crucial thing about what I am trying to import.

I am trying to import `channelx` which is in **File 1** and I am trying to use the variable in **File 2**.

**Output**

User: /setrestart #channel

Bot: All server restart logs will now go to `${channelx}`.

User: /restart

Bot: Embed sent in `channelx`

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. But the reason why it doesn't work is very clear, the exported object from **File 1** does not contain a `.send()` method. There is `.execute()` method, `name` and `description` properties. Were you trying to call the `.execute()`?

Comment: I am trying to import `channelx` which is defined in File 1. I accidently forgot to include the variable in file 2. The code I am trying to run is `setr.channelx.send(restart)`
Edit: I am trying to use `.send()` in this case. As I am trying to send the embed in `channelx`.

Comment: The variable `channelx` is accessible only in the function scope of `execute()`, you can't import it. Basically after the function goes out of scope the variable is lost.

Comment: Alright! I'll try that instead.

Comment: I have written an answer, you can check that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `channelx` is accessible only in the function scope of `execute()`, you can't import it. Basically after the function goes out of scope the variable is lost. Use a global object, note that the object is destroyed when the program exits. So if you are trying to make some kind of bot's configuration, you want to save the object to a file.

*Here is an example of how to properly implement what you are trying to do.*

**File 1 (`file1.js`):**

```js
// ... Load storage from a JSON file ...
const storage = {};

module.exports = {
    name: "setrestart",
    description: "sets the restart channel",
    async execute(message, args) {

        // ... Permission checking ...

        const channelx = message.mentions.channels.first() ||
            message.guild.channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === args[0]);
        
        if (!channelx) {
            return message.channel.send(
                `:x: Please specify the channel where server restarts will go!`
            );
        }

        // Store restart channel id per guild
        storage[message.guild.id] = channelx.id;
        message.reply(`All server restart logs will now go to ${channelx}.`);

        // ... Write to the storage JSON file and update it with new data ...

    },    
};

module.exports.storage = storage;
```

**File 2 (`file2.js`):**

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const file1 = require("./file1.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "restart",
    description: "send a restart message in status channel",
    async execute(message, args) {
        
        // ... Permission checking ...

        const restart = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(" Server Restarted! ")
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setTimestamp();

        const channelId = file1.storage[message.guild.id];
        // If there is no restart channel set, default to the system channel
        if (!channelId) channelId = message.guild.systemChannelID;

        const channel = await message.client.channels.fetch(channelId);
        channel.send(restart);

    },    
};
```

<sub>Note that I have remove some parts of your code, to make it work on my machine.</sub>

<sub>Using discord.js `^12.5.3`.</sub>

Comment: I really appreciate it this does exactly what I wanted! I cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't use the `module.exports` in that way. You should just add the `channelx` to the exports instead.

using `this.channelx = channelx`.

Comment: Changing `module.exports` won't really help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how importing and exporting works. Your `channelx` variable is defined within the execution of a function, and you are not returning it.

I am not sure how the whole Discord API works and what are the shapes that get returned, but you should be able to do something like this:

### File 1

```
module.exports = {
  name: "setrestart",
  description: "sets the restart channel",
  async execute(message, args) {
    // ... everything as per your file
    message.reply(`All server restart logs will now go to ${channelx}.`);

    return channelx;
  },    
};
```

### File 2

```
module.exports = {
  name: "restart",
  description: "send a restart message in status channel",
  async execute(message, args) {
    // ... everything the same as per your file
    const channelx = await setr.execute(message, args);
    channelx.send(restart);
  },    
};
```

---

Basically, what is happening here is that the first module exposes a function that figures out your target channel and then returns it.

Once you return it, you can do whatever you want with that.

Please be aware that your first function might not need to be `async` as you don't have any `await` instruction.

---

Read more about scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: Thanks! This sort of helped me so I cannot import the `channelx` variable into File 2? Unless I use a database?

Comment: No, this is not about using a database. The variable is declared within the scope of the function and when the function is done is not accessible anymore. However, the function can `return` the variable (i.e. pass it over to someone requesting it)